# MVVMCross SimpleIoc: how to Ungegister all service instances

Tags: mvvmcross, simpleioc

I want to unregister all service instances of SimpleIoC.

**CODE**

```
 public class IoCRegistry
   {
        private List<Type> RegistryList = new List<Type>();

        public void Register<TInterface, TClass>() where TInterface : class where TClass : class, TInterface
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TInterface, TClass>();
            RegistryList.Add(typeof(TInterface));
        }

        public void UnregisterAll()
        {
            foreach (var item in RegistryList)
            {
                try
                {
                   var sdss = SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances(item);

                    foreach (var instance in SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances(item))
                    {
                       SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(instance);
                    }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }
 }
```

Here  `SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(instance);` is not removing instance because when I try to locate the service and check its instance, it still has older instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you see [the code](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20(PCL)/Ioc/SimpleIoc.cs#L457) Reset is what you are looking for, it will remove all registrations and previous instances, i.e. clear all lookups that the IoC have.

```cs
SimpleIoc.Default.Reset();
```

Your code isn't working because that clear only the cache instance of the registration as you can see [here](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20(PCL)/Ioc/SimpleIoc.cs#L519) in the code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes the given instance from the cache. The class itself remains
/// registered and can be used to create other instances.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TClass">The type of the instance to be removed.</typeparam>
/// <param name="instance">The instance that must be removed.</param>
public void Unregister<TClass>(TClass instance)
    where TClass : class
```

If you want to do that one type by one you'd have to use:

```
/// <summary>
/// Unregisters a class from the cache and removes all the previously
/// created instances.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TClass">The class that must be removed.</typeparam>
[SuppressMessage(
    "Microsoft.Design",
    "CA1004",
    Justification = "This syntax is better than the alternatives.")]
public void Unregister<TClass>()
    where TClass : class
```

HIH

Comment: Reset will also unregister the services along with its instances, I want to keep registrations and just remove the instances for those services.

Comment: oh well, it's wierd because you're using the correct method then. How are you checking if it's the same instance as before unregistering?